# 2 digit argument for args in Thread() do not work

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multithreading

Here I have the relevant code snippets for my question:

```
from threading import Thread
.
.
.
def do_post(thread_no):
       print "Starting thread no: " + thread_no + "\n"

.
.
.

for i in range(0,MAX_THREADS):
        try:
            t=Thread(target=do_post, args=('%d'%i))
            t.start()

.
.
```

When MAX_THREADS > 10 I get the error message : `TypeError: do_post() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`

How do I make it accept a 2 digit number ?

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to pass a `tuple` to `args`:

```
args=('%d'%i,)
```

As you have it, you're simply passing a string which is getting unpacked into more arguments than it should be.

consider:

```
def printstuff(*args):
    print args,len(args)

printstuff(*("1"))   #('1',) 1
printstuff(*("10"))  #('1', '0') 2
printstuff(*("10",)) #('10',) 1
```

Answer (score 1):

`args=(...,)` needs to be passed a sequence, not a scalar value, so put a comma after `('%d'%i)`:

```
t = Thread(target=do_post, args=('%d'%i,))
```

`('%d'%i)` is the same as the string `'%d'%i`.

`('%d'%i, )` is the tuple with `'%d'%i` as its first element.

---

By the way, however, you do not have to pass a thread number.

You could use:

```
 name = threading.current_thread().name
```

instead.

---

```
import threading

def worker():
    name = threading.current_thread().name
    print('I am: {n}'.format(n = name))

for i in range(4):
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
    t.daemon=True
    t.start()

# I am: Thread-1
# I am: Thread-2
# I am: Thread-3
# I am: Thread-4
```

---

If you wish to change the name of the thread, you can pass whatever string you like through the `name` parameter. For instance,

```
t = threading.Thread(target=worker, name=str(i))
```

results in

```
I am: 0
I am: 1
I am: 2
I am: 3
```

Comment: Thanks. Didnt know the existence of .name . Makes the code neater.